# solaris ssh ctrl arrow keys do not work

Tags: ssh, solaris, putty

I connect to SunOS 5.11 11.3 machine via ssh using putty.

In terminal ctrl + arrow keys are not moving cursor to the previous/next words.

There is simple bash terminal on the Solaris machine.

Do you know how to fix this issue?

In the past I had [this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/94436/how-to-configure-putty-so-that-home-end-pgup-pgdn-work-properly-in-bash) and already applied the solution (set terminal type string in putty to "linux"), but now I also want arrow keys working.

Comment: You'll need to tell people what shell you are using and (given that you've mucked around with terminal types per the other Q&A) how you have mucked around with terminal types, in particular what the value of the `TERM` environment variable seen by your shell is.

Comment: @JdeBP how do I get ```TERM``` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PuTTY doesn't do that.  It's a feature of xterm, and is one of many features of xterm not provided by PuTTY: sending different escape sequences depending on whether the <kbd>Control</kbd> and/or <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed at the same time.

xterm-style modifiers for cursor keys are supported in ncurses by a extended terminal description (not part of conventional X/Open or SVr4 terminfo).  However, PuTTY does not implement xterm-style modifiers in this case.  For a long time, it used the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to switch between *normal* and *application* modes for the cursor keys, and recently changed the modifier to the <kbd>Control</kbd> key:

```
commit 41e1a586fb956539a74bc446984a100e0138cd77                                 
Author: Simon Tatham                                          
Date:   Sat Dec 8 08:25:32 2018 +0000 

     - swapping the arrow keys between normal (ESC [ A) and application         
       (ESC O A) is now done by pressing Ctrl with them, and _not_ by           
       pressing Shift. That was how it was always supposed to work, and         
       how it's worked on GTK all along, but on Windows it's been done by       
       Shift as well since 2010, due to a bug at the call site of               
       format_arrow_key() introduced when I originally wrote that function.
```

but that did not change the *escape* sequence used.  In the change comment, *`ESC [ A`* refers to the normal-mode up-arrow, and *`ESC O A`* to the application-mode up-arrow.

ncurses provides an accurate terminal description for [PuTTY](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_Pu_T_T_Y), but in this case the terminal description is irrelevant because *bash* uses hard-coded escapes in `.inputrc` (*zsh* does a little better, but also is lacking in this area--see the [xterm manual](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Special-Keys)).  Even supposing that *bash* used the terminal description, the information is not available to *bash* because the terminal description's names cannot be read using a termcap application (such as *bash*).  As mentioned, *zsh* is a little better, but it does not read **extensions**.

Using

```
infocmp -x xterm
```

you might notice `kLFT5`, `kRIT5`, `kUP5`, `kDN5` (which are the names given to the control-modified cursor keys--all extensions), but you will not find those in the [**`putty`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-putty) terminal description because PuTTY doesn't do that.

Comment: So, is this impossible with Putty or I still can modify ```.inputrc``` on the machine to achieve the desirable effect?

Comment: impossible with Putty (PuTTY doesn't do that), and in any case poorly supported by bash/zsh (hard-coding things is a last-resort approach by developers).

Comment: Note for myself: [ctrl + arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029118/bash-ctrl-to-move-cursor-between-words-strings).