# Home/End buttons don't work when connecting to Solaris via Putty

Tags: solaris, putty

I am using Putty to connect to Solaris machine (SunOS 5.11 11.3) from my Win10 PC (workplace mandates win, so it is necessary).

Despite trying different terminal definition strings and different keyboard settings in Putty I still get one or more of the next issues:

1. Home/End buttons either don't work at all (or just Home if 'rxvt' set as "The Home and End keys" in "Terminal->Keyboard")
2. Or `screen` complaining that it cannot recognize TERM (trying to use 'linux' as terminal-type string in "Connection->Data"). And I absolutely need screen, yeah.

The closest I can get to something normal is:

- Terminal->Keyboard:

  - The Home and End keys - rxvt
  - The Function keys and keypad - Xterm R6
- Connection->Data:

  - Terminal-type string - xterm-256color

But the 'End' button still doesn't work.

Who knows how to properly configure Putty in order for this buttons to work?

Maybe there is other freeware tool which I can use to achieve the desirable effect?

Comment: You were told at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590527/5132 that getting modified arrow keys from PuTTY is impossible.  Why are you asking it again?

Comment: @JdeBP maybe someone will be willing to help me to fix at least part of the issue (I get that it won't be you, chill). I'd very like to have at least home/end buttons to work properly, but they are not.

Comment: Someone, Thomas Dickey, already has helped you.  You've just ignored it and asked the same thing again.  Why?

Comment: @ThomasDickey, partially. I probably have to rephrase the question.

Comment: You could install Cygwin on your Windows machine, and use xterm :-)

Comment: @ThomasDickey but can I save sessions/credentials like putty using cygwin+xterm? I guess I can make another rsa key just for the sake of logging in to machines and then scp it to every machine I am using... but it is not what I want. And some machines have different credentials... and it gets more and more messy. The infrastructure is way too complicated over there.